# Create single AAR file from multiple modules using Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to generate a single AAR file from my multi-modules Android project.

I am trying to come up with my own solution that will fits my needs. I know that I don't have duplicated resources and external dependencies (like the Support Libraries) are provided by the people using my lib.

My structure is similar to this:

/root
|- lib1
|- lib2

dependencies {
 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile project(path: ':lib1')
    compile project(path: ':lib2')
}

when I create AAR file it will generate three file (root.aar, lib1.aar, lib2.aar) but I want to create only one root.aar file with which contain all dependency (activities and resources).

please guide me how to achieve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: After expending three day finally I got a solution for this.

Comment: please follow bellow link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4pN4aWiG-LVVGZSdE9YeFhFeE0